# Checkbox id keeps changing in webpage causing selenium script to fail

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox

I am trying to automate a click on a certain checkbox. However after every run the checkbox id changes and script fails to find the element. Is there an alternate way of writing an xpath

```
<span id="field_key$0993573c-83b4-30d4-9139-44e44b496d0f$1food_contamination-checkbox" class="v-checkbox v-widget" ca-help-field-id="undefined">
<input id="gwt-uid-193" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0" checked=""/>
<label for="gwt-uid-193"/>
</span>
```

xpath I used was this:

```
//*[@id='gwt-uid-193']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parent `<span>` id is fixed you can use it and go one level down to the checkbox

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#field_key$0993573c-83b4-30d4-9139-44e44b496d0f$1food_contamination-checkbox > input"));
```

Or use the parent class

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".checkbox > input"));
```

And if you have only one checkbox you can use the type attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type='checkbox']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. We can use `xpath` based on the position of the checkbox, *i.e.*:

```
// input[@type='checkbox'])[position()=3]
```

This can be used for radio buttons as well. Replace `checkbox` with `radio`.